# Azure Build/Release Pipelines for SQL Scripts

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, cicd

We have an on-prem instance of SQL Server 2016 that I'd like to create an automated CI/CD pipeline for in Azure DevOps. All of our database code is managed in an Azure Git repo where stored procedures, functions, views etc are stored as individual scripts.

I'd like to create build and release pipelines using just the SQL scripts without using a .dacpac file or Visual Studio solution, however all of the tutorials I'm finding are suggesting to use those. My vision is to have new features (e.g. updates to stored procedures, new functions) be worked on branches, have them merged into my 'main' branch in Azure Git, have that trigger a build which would combine all of the scripts into one file, create an artifact, deploy the artifact to my SQL Server.

I'm having difficulty even finding the functionality to create builds in this manner (I've been using the classic editor in the Build pipelines). Is this even possible, and if so, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: We use (yaml) pipelines using powershell tasks to run sql scripts? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @GetShifting That's an interesting idea. Would you mind explaining a high level overview of the process of whats going on?  What is the output of the build?  Do the PS scripts just invoke sqlcmd to execute the scripts? TIA

Comment: sure, we use it for multiple purposes, but to give you an idea, in the build we create sql scripts for (dotnet) data migration purposes. We also have some default SQL scripts for database creation and security. In the deploy stage we copy all the sql script to the database server, make a remote ps connection to the server and use invoke-sqlcmd to run the scripts.